# Deeplink on Chrome for Android not working properly

Tags: android, deep-linking, appsflyer

I having a problem to make an Apps Flyer OneLink to work properly on Android with Chrome browser. On any other browser everything works fine.

The problem is, deeplink doesn't always open the app when I try open thru Chrome. Sometimes it work, but for a lot of users are only redirected to fallback url.

Here is a deeplink to test:

https://sparkle.onelink.me/twwu?pid=test&af_force_deeplink=true&af_dp=https%3A%2F%2Fsparkle.hotmart.com%2Fu%2FLipeDuoli%3Futm_campaign%3D0000-0000-0000&af_web_dp=https%3A%2F%2Fsparkle.hotmart.com%2Fusers%2FLipeDuoli&af_ios_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsparkle.hotmart.com%2Fdownload&af_android_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsparkle.hotmart.com%2Fdownload

I`m already did everything that says here:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

Thx

Comment: you may ask your users to make sure their chrome browser is up to date.  They JUST released a patch to android chrome that, when used embedded, was causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facing a similar issue. Not able to reproduce it myself, but some users are reporting this issue. What I could reproduce was that tapping the shortlink opens the app chooser popup and asks whether to open it in the app or Chrome. Previously, it did not show such app chooser dialog. I think it might be related to changes in `Chrome` itself because `Chrome 79` introduced such an issue on `Android` as you can see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1039612).